# How to export multiple components from an index file in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Here is my index.jsx file:

```
import Navbar from './Navbar/Navbar';
import Greeting from './Greeting/Greeting'
import Project from './Project/Project';
import About from './About/About';
import Contact from './Contact/Contact';
import Footer from './Footer/Footer';

export default {
  Navbar,
  Greeting,
  Project,
  About,
  Contact,
  Footer,
};
```

And my App.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar} from './components';

// import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

When I call to import `Navbar` through the `index.jsx` file, I got this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module */sre/components/index. isx?
> App.isx:4
> t=1672200538218' does not provide an export named "Navbar'

What wrong I got if I call Navbar through index file? Thank you so much!

How can I call to import many components througnt index file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of importing them and then exporting them, you could directly export them as below. But for this to work you would want to use named exports, like `export function Navbar()` instead of
`export default function Navbar()`.

```
export { Navbar } from "./Navbar/Navbar";
export { Greeting } from "./Greeting/Greeting";
export { Project } from "./Project/Project";
export { About } from "./About/About";
export { Contact } from "./Contact/Contact";
export { Footer } from "./Footer/Footer";
```

But if you would rather keep your `default` export, you should be doing as below instead of what you have:

```
export { defautl as Navbar } from "./Navbar/Navbar";
export { defautl as Greeting } from "./Greeting/Greeting";
export { defautl as Project } from "./Project/Project";
export { defautl as About } from "./About/About";
export { defautl as Contact } from "./Contact/Contact";
export { defautl as Footer } from "./Footer/Footer";
```

You can learn more about `export` on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#re-exporting_aggregating).

Comment: Thank you for you help!
For the first way, export name with out default still got error. (Required an export default)
The second way is worked. (It seem be risk because in one file we only have 1 default export)

Comment: My pleasure @nhont! I see, but even if you have only one export in a file, you could use a named export, allowing you to use the first concise solution.